# Why inserting a doc result to an array

Tags: apostrophe-cms

using Apostrophe for tasks purposes, I wonder why `self.docs['my-module'].insert(...)` result to an array with my element in third position in the callback.

Expected: get the plain object directly.

Steps to reproduce :

```
// lib/modules/my-module/index.js
module.exports = {
  construct: (self, options) => {
    self.apos.modules['apostrophe-tags'].insert({},
      {
        title: 'test'
      },
      {permissions: false},
      (err, doc) => {
        console.log(doc); // [undefined, undefined, THE_DOC, undefined, undefined]
      }
    );
  }
};
```

`console.log` show you an array where the data is "in the middle".

My worries behind it is to make safe the way to do : `doc[2]`. And I'm unable to find why in the source code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer: this is now supported in the way you were hoping. The `insert` methods of `apostrophe-pieces` and its subclasses now deliver the inserted document to their callbacks as the second argument. Ditto for `update`.

Comment: That's an unexpected behaviour for me but it work ! I use `apostrophe-tags` in the example because he extend `apostrophe-pieces`. Thanks :)

Comment: Oops, you're quite right about apostrophe-tags extending apostrophe-pieces. Edited.